# How to pass aws provider credentials to null_resource local-exec provisioner?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Has anyone come up with a decent way to do this?

In short, you have a `provider "aws"`, configured via env vars or profile, with or without `sts`, it doesn't matter. Maybe you have several.

Now you want to call out to the `aws` cli because something isn't well implemented in the aws provider. In my case, I need to generate and upload some sensitive information directly to an S3 bucket that I do not want in the state file. In any case, it was `s3 sync`, so the action is idempotent.

However, there appears to be no way to pass the provider credentials - permanent, env var, profile to temporary sts - to a `null_resource` clause:

```
provider "aws" {
  # set using explicit setting or profile or however
  alias = "myaws"
}

resource "null_resource" "cli" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws <do something>"
    environment {
      # happy to pass AWS_PROFILE or AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID / AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY here...
      # if there were a way to retrieve it from the "myaws" provider
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Python+boto3 would probably work better than the AWS CLI here for what you want.

Comment: Maybe. Or maybe I need a script. Or some other binary. Any of the above still would require a null_resource local-exec which has the same provider credential passing issue.

Comment: How are you getting the credentials for your AWS provider? Do you assume a role? If so why not just assume the role via the AWS CLI as well?

Comment: @deitch No you would not have that problem with Python+Boto3 because it has intrinsic support for credentials so there would be no passing from Terraform.

Comment: The CLI also has, as do most sdks. In tf, I might have passed the creds directly, might have consumed via env vars, might have used a profile, might have assumed a role, might have multiple sets of creds/roles. The beauty of the aws resources in tf is that none needs to know, it just gets the right creds to act. An external child command should be able to do the same.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR - in some cases direct creds, in others profile (via the config|credentials files), in others assume. Either way, it already is in the "right state" in terraform, and should be able to "pass it down", but cannot. Looks like there is some new life on the issue, but like to see how people work around it. See https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-null/issues/3#issuecomment-479117650

Comment: If you're using the `~/.aws/credentials` file or environment variables (or EC2 instance metadata) then the AWS CLI will just transparently work. If you need to assume a role then you can also do this via the AWS CLI by running `aws sts assume-role`. If you're using hardcoded credentials in the provider block then you should stop doing this because that's a bad practice that is the kind of thing that leads to people accidentally pushing their credentials to source control.

Comment: Yeah, we definitely do not hard-code credentials; never would. It sounds like you are assuming that there is one default profile, or one set of creds. If not, then you have to specify the profile in the `provider` part, might even do an `assume role` there. Whatever the "default" is in my credentials may or may not be the right creds/role to use when executing the command. terraform did a pretty good job giving control via the vars and `alias` option to `provider "aws"{}`, and it is using the right one, but I have no way to pass it to the `local-exec`

Comment: anyone finding this now would be recommended to use dynamic provider credentials if using TFC/E: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/enterprise/workspaces/dynamic-provider-credentials

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an AWS role_arn into a `local-exec` script. For example:

```
variable "aws_role" {
  type        = string
  description = "AWS role for local exec to assume"
  default     = "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/DBMigrateRole"
}

resource "null_resource" "call-db-migrate" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    command = <<EOF
set -e
CREDENTIALS=(`aws sts assume-role \
  --role-arn ${var.aws_role} \
  --role-session-name "db-migration-cli" \
  --query "[Credentials.AccessKeyId,Credentials.SecretAccessKey,Credentials.SessionToken]" \
  --output text`)

unset AWS_PROFILE
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="$${CREDENTIALS[0]}"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="$${CREDENTIALS[1]}"
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="$${CREDENTIALS[2]}"

aws sts get-caller-identity
EOF
  }
}
```

Credit to https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/8242#issuecomment-586687360 .